# implement blogger like page layout management C# asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, blogger

i was trying to build a page template creation wizard.Something similar to the blogger page layout management section.Like rearranging the widgets using drag and drop and adding new widgets too 
Can any one provide any good tutorial or articles which show how to implement such a thing.